# SLD encoding with GeoServer REST Configuration

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-rest-api, rest

I am using the GeoServer REST Configuration to add the following SLD file to GeoServer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>MyWorkspace:MyLayer</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>MyLayer_default_style</Name>
      <Title>MyLayer</Title>
      <Abstract>Default style for Mylayer</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Polygon</Title>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#CBCCCC</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#CBCCCC</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I have used the example from the [GeoServer REST Docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-curl.html#changing-a-feature-type-style) and the sld file is added to GeoServer like expected. But the encoding of the sld file in GeoServer is now **"UTF-8"** instead of **"ISO-8859-1"** which I declared. 
See the SLD created by GeoServer below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>MyWorkspace:MyLayer</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>MyLayer_default_style</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>MyLayer</sld:Title>
      <sld:Abstract>Default style for Mylayer</sld:Abstract>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Title>Polygon</sld:Title>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#CBCCCC</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#CBCCCC</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I have tested this using GeoServer 2.1 (all RC and final release).

How can I add the SLD by using the GeoServer REST Configuration with my declared encoding and not "UTF-8"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you stumbled across a bug. Your next best course of action to file a geoserver bug report with the all the information provided here to reproduce the problem.

This [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-3983) has been resolved and the solution is now to use the [`raw`](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/styles.html#raw) parameter in the REST request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will file it as a bug on GeoServer Bug Tracker.