# Upload already created SLD styles in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, sld

I have locally created some SLDs and uploaded to the GeoServer corresponding 'styles' folder

The idea is not to go through the GeoServer user interface to create the styles again (copy and paste via UI), but that GeoServer already finds these and let me chose them when creating a new layer

I restarted Tomcat, but GeoServer still does not see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works I'm afraid. When you add an SLD file to GeoServer it has to create some supporting configuration to go with them.

First, when using the GUI there is a `load style` button that is much easier to use than cutting and pasting the SLD in to the editor.

Second, if you want to avoid the GUI and script your uploads then you need to use the [REST API which tells GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/) what you want to do and lets it take care of configuring your styles. This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9623/sld-encoding-with-geoserver-rest-configuration) may help, or any of [these questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeoserver-rest-api%5D%20sld)